# C# Variable Scoping

Tags: c#, scope, opentext

I'm new to C#, having written a little in a CMS, but my background is mostly JavaScript related. That said, I am working in the "Scripting" client in OpenText Capture Center. When executing the code below I get the error "The Name 'srfOnly' does not exist in the current context"

If I move the variable declarations to within the function, I get the same error, If I move them to them to global I get the same error but on a different line number.

How can I access the variables srfOnly and otherDocs throughout the code?

```
    //Parameters:
    //DataPool data
    //ITrace trace

    // Checking if condition is fulfilled.
    if (checkDocuments(data))
    {
       // Getting batch field named 'cc_SkipValidation'.
       // Setting new value.

       DOKuStar.Data.Xml.Bool skipValidationField = data.RootNode.Fields["cc_SkipValidation"] as DOKuStar.Data.Xml.Bool;
       bool srfOnly = false;
       bool otherDocs = false;

        if(otherDocs == true)
        {
             skipValidationField.SetValue(false);
        }
        if(srfOnly == true && otherDocs == false)
        {
             skipValidationField.SetValue(true);
          skipValidationField.State = DataState.Ok;
        }

    }
    // !!! Closing bracket is neccessary !!!
    }
    // ------------------ Functions
    public bool checkDocuments(DataPool dataPool)
    {
        foreach (Document doc in dataPool.RootNode.Documents)
        {
             if (doc.Name == "ServiceRequestForm")
             {
               srfOnly = true;
             }
             else if (doc.Name != "ServiceRequestForm")
             {
                 otherDocs = true;
             }
        }


    trace.WriteInfo("Trace info for Validation of srfOnly = " + srfOnly);
    trace.WriteInfo("Trace info for Validation of otherDocs = " + otherDocs);

    // !!! No closing bracket needed !!!
```

Comment: Your formatting is off, some brackets appear sequentially on the same column.  You might want to edit...

Comment: `No closing bracket needed`  That's interesting.

Comment: Agreed with the no closing brackets being interesting. That was taken from an example provided by the software that I modified to get to this point, and it errors while adding/moving brackets around.

Comment: Is this code that then gets put into a larger file or something? The fact that you don't have a method declaration and opening brace and then don't need the closing brace suggests to me it is going to do something like put `static void Main()  {` before your code and then a `}` after it... If that is the case it would be very helpful to know.

Comment: @Chris: There is a little-known feature of C# that allows it to be used in a "scripting" mode where you can build up little sample programs in a "REPL" style; essentially, as you've surmised, the code you type in gets added as members of a class. Presumably that is what the OP is doing here, though I am not familiar with "OpenText Capture Center". (I did, however, consider working for OpenText after college; I'm sure it would have been fine, but I think going to Microsoft was the better choice.:-) )

Comment: @Chris: An interesting question that I do not know the answer to is whether OpenText used the C# scripting APIs to build a principled, supported scripting solution or if they just are pasting code snippets in an ad-hoc manner behind the scenes and running the compiler; the presence of comments that indicate that oddly-placed closing braces are required here and there makes me think that the latter might be the case.  I'm not sure that the original poster's question is answerable without knowing more about how OpenText is hosting C#.

Comment: @Chris - "Is this code that then gets put into a larger file or something?"
That's a fantastic question, my assumption is yes I'm still very new to OpenText so I'm learning about it as I'm going.

Comment: @TheSellout: If it is then you'll want to look at the code with that wrapper put on it since it will make more sense of the scoping. For example normally fields get put at the top of the class but in this case the top of the class is actually inside a method whose declaration you can't see.

Comment: @Chris - I totally agree, I just don't have access to the wrapping code. I'm flying blind a bit within the software. I appreciate all of the feedback and help.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are limited in scope by where they exist in your code. If you declare a variable within an if{} block, the variable only exists inside that block. If you declare a variable inside of a class but not within a class method, the variable is accessible to every method in the class. If you want a variable to be accessible to every class with in a project, you would normally declare it in a public static class.

For example...

```
public static class GlobalClass
{
    public static string myGlobal="";    
}  

class myClass
{
    string myClassVariable = "";
    private void method()
    {
        //myGlobal is accessible using this
        GlobalClass.myGlobal ="some value";
        //myClassVariable is accessible here
        myClassVariable = "somevalue";
        if(condition)
        {
            //myClassVariable is also accessible here
            myClassVariable = "somevalue";
            string ifBlockVariable = "";
        }
        //ifBlockVariable is not accessible here
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a number of errors in your code; `Class` vs `class`, `myGlobal` needs to be `static`, and so on.  Also note that having globals variables like this is a "worst practice" in C#; don't be encouraging it.

Comment: Yes errors. Thanks for pointing it out. It was typed free hand.  As far as answering the OP's question, making a Global class is how you make a variable accessible throughout code. Of course you can can pass variables as arguments as you should in most cases, but having a global class is useful is some cases.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is only accessible within the current block (and the blocks within that block). If you want to access the `srfOnly` variable within the checkDocuments method you can pass it as a parameter:

`public bool checkDocuments(DataPool dataPool, bool srfOnly)`

If you want the variable to be accessible from anywhere in the class, you can declare it as a a property of the class or an instance variable as following:

`private bool _srfOnly;`